# How to Update a Parent Scope Variable from within ng-repeat Expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I've run into a situation where I had to update a scope variable from within an ng-repeat expression (ng-class call within ng-repeat in fact).

```
<div id="page" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
.
 <section id="body" ng-init="countMis = {num:0}">
.
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="upperCaseLetter in alphabet.specialsUpper" ng-controller="letterController">
    <td>{{upperCaseLetter}}</td>
    <td>{{filteredLetter=(upperCaseLetter | lowercase)}}</td>
    <td>{{alphabet.specialsLower[$index]}}</td>
    <td><span ng-class="lowercaseEqual($index,filteredLetter)"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in app.js:

```
function letterController($scope)
{
    $scope.lowercaseEqual = function(indx,letter)
    {       
        var returnStr="";

        if(letter == $scope.alphabet.specialsLower[indx])
        {
             returnStr = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
        }
        else
        {   
            $scope.countMis.num = $scope.countMis.num + 1;
            returnStr = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";
        }

        return returnStr;
    };

}
```

[image: Example App Screenshot]

Ng-repeat is in a child controller and data I want to update is in its parent controller. I know you've read same question many times, please keep reading and see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bogac/78w9E/) example.

So expression function checks filtered data of that particular ng-repeat iteration, if it doesn't match with some other corresponding parent scope variable it returns a class but also it should update parent scope counter. 
As those expressions don't evaluate just once, but at least once (because of dirty check in digest) it results counter being incremented more than once for each case.

I've solved my problem by counting classes applied to that particular data after ng-repeat (you'll see in the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bogac/78w9E/) example).
However I think I may run into same problem in the future, so I want to learn how to update parent scope within an expression of ng-repeat iteration.

I've put a second [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bogac/zJQw6/), I've tried using a factory on both parent controller and child, hoping to update a common variable for both controllers. When I log (consol.log) each iteration and factory method variable, it shows iteration times + 1 (still false value), but it's not reflected on page expression...doesn't make sense at all.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

[JsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Bogac/78w9E/)    [JsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Bogac/zJQw6/)

Comment: Your fiddles have errors, can you get those cleaned up first?

Comment: what is your question, do you want to solve this question another way? I don't get why did you use indivual controllers to each row... what is the reason behind that?

Comment: I didn't use individual controllers for each row. There are 2 controllers. One main controller (with data), and one with basic functionality (child of main controller). What I want to achieve is manipulation of main controller's data from child controller for the case of an expression for ng-repeat iteration. @wickY26

Comment: They seem to work, please check again. @ZackArgyle

Answer (score 1):

Since watched expressions (like the one implicitely set up by the `ng-class` directive) *"can execute multiple times per **[$digest()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)** and should be idempotent"*.
You should understand what the **[$watch()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)** and **[$digest()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)** functions do and look for resources regarding **[Angular's digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)**.

So, incrementing a counter inside a watchExpression is not a good idea.
Counting classes seems ok though.

---

BTW, the factory-approach will help you share data across scopes, but it won't help with the "multiple executions per digest cycle" problem. Furthermore, it might be redundant in your situation, since the child- and parent-scopes can share data directly.
In any case, for the results to be displayed you have to "bind" the factory's `getMismatchCount()` function with the `getMismatchCount()` function that you use in your HTML (in `Mismatches Count from Factory: {{getMismatchCount()}}`):

```
function mainCtrl($scope, $window, repeatFactory)
    ...
    $scope.getMismatchCount = repeatFactory.getMismatchCount;
```